# How do I connect the points in this plot with a line using ggplot?

Tags: r, ggplot2

I have a tibble of median incomes for age groups. I can make a ggplot that plots the points for median income for each age group. My question is, how do I also draw straight lines between each point? My understanding is that geom_line is supposed to accomplish this, but for some reason it is not working for me.

I realize there are other plots that would show the same information, but my purpose is pedagogical, so it would really be nice to be able have this exact plot. A reproducible example is here:

```
library(tidyverse)

# This is the exact tibble I'm using (code generated using dput):

trouble <- structure(list(agegroup = structure(1:17, .Label = c("[15,20]", 
                                                     "(20,25]", "(25,30]", "(30,35]", "(35,40]", "(40,45]", "(45,50]", 
                                                     "(50,55]", "(55,60]", "(60,65]", "(65,70]", "(70,75]", "(75,80]", 
                                                     "(80,85]", "(85,90]", "(90,95]", "(95,100]"), class = "factor"), 
               inctot = c(4100, 20000, 32000, 39800, 45500, 45000, 42950, 
                          43200, 41200, 37000, 26000, 26000, 20650, 24000, 25500, 23115, 
                          1900)), class = c("tbl_df", "tbl", "data.frame"), row.names = c(NA, 
                                                                                          -17L))

# Create a scatterplot of the points:

ggplot(trouble,aes(x = agegroup, y = inctot)) +
  geom_point()
```

That works exactly as expected. But if I try to run

```
ggplot(trouble,aes(x = agegroup, y = inctot)) +
  geom_point() +
  geom_line()
```

It gives me the error

> geom_path: Each group consists of only one observation. Do you need to adjust
>   the group aesthetic?

All I want to do is connect these points with lines. How?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This solves the problem:

```
ggplot(trouble,aes(x = agegroup, y = inctot,group=1)) +
    geom_point() +
    geom_line()
```

Comment: Thanks very much, @Duck. That does exactly what I want.